# Remove space from php url $url

Tags: php

user submit a from and It also generate a link. When user put a space in their names or phone. Space also appear in url. I want to replace this space from url to nospace.
My code is here

```
elseif($company == 5) {
    $ip = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])[0];
    $sub = explode('|',$s3);
    $str = ltrim($newphonecode, '+');
    $num = $str.''.$newphnnum;
    $url = 'http://go.247traffic.com/api/forextb/?api_username=allconverts&
          api_password=MegaStart21&module=Customer&command=add&
          firstname='.$firstname.'&lastname='.$lastname.'&email='.urlencode($emaillead).'&
          phone='.$num.'&password='.$password.'&country='.$country.'&language='.$language.'&
          campaignid='.urlencode($s).'&
          subCampaign='.urlencode($sub[1]).''.htmlspecialchars('&currency').'='.
          $currency.'&ip='.$ip;
```

Comment: Use PHP's `preg_replace` for this. Assuming your phone number should only contain digits, use `preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', '123 456 789')` -> `123456789`

Comment: You should never put the password value in the URL

Comment: You should always use a `https` secured URL

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers which is a walk in the park compared to managing people's names as data. Don't change the data, use urlencode()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()` for this purpose:

```
$str = " Hello  World";
echo "With space: " . $str;
echo "<br>";
echo "Without space: " . str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

Output will look like:

with space:  `Hello World`

without space: `HelloWorld`